# RAM memory allocated to Windows 7 64 bit guest machine in VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, memory

I have a laptop with 12 GB of RAM running Xubuntu.  Then I have Windows 7 64 bit running as a guest machine in VirtualBox.

My question: I have allocated 6 GB of RAM to Windows 7 guest machine in the VirtualBox settings, but when I run Windows 7 and check computer properties, it shows me the *installed RAM is only 1.87 GB*.  Why doesn't Windows 7 show the installed 6 GB of RAM that I have allocated to that?

[image: Screenshot of Control Panel - System]

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of Control Panel → System.

Comment: Interesting.  I had a similar issue when the HOST operating system was 32-bit Linux Mint (a Ubuntu derivitive). VirtualBox was unable to give any GUEST OS more than around 2GB RAM *regardless* of settings. Solution? I had to install Mint 64-bit as the host OS.  Then VirtualBox worked as expected. So... are you running Xubuntu 32-bit or 64-bit on your host???

Comment: You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Comment: Looks “normal”. No idea, sorry. Just one last test: What happens when you use a power-of-two size like 4 GB?